# will a given vector have unique direction ratios

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

can we conclude that a given vector has unique direction ratios and not infinite like a straight line.

as direction ratios are unique and are equal to the direction cosines in case of a unit vector,hope for a given finite vector,the direction ratios are fixed and can not be infinite.

Comment: any answers from any user.

Answer (score 0):

No , the direction cosines are unique , there are infinitely many direction ratios .

Direction cosines are the cosines of angles made by the vector with the positive X,y and z axes , where the direction ratios are multiples of the direction cosines .

Comment: but direction ratios are just lengths of the bases of the triangles formed,hope a finte vector carries a finite triangle and so direction ratios.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right direction ratios are unique for a given unified vector,but direction ratios can be infinite of a same direction cosines
vectors

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).